# How to check more then two id at a time

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have been create a catalog service like blow json pattern.

Json pattern :

```
{
    "id": "b01ee924-78d3-4f3a-9568-5ee80cbad7a7",
    "VendorName": "string",
    "Industy": [
        {
            "Id": "0350ac6c-ca15-4a1e-9211-ad078fbf443c",
            "IdustryId": 0,
            "IdustryName": "string",
            "Category": [
                {
                    "id": "a7b71770-9daf-4b67-b471-0a8390843544",
                    "Name": "string",
                    "Description": "string",
                    "Subcategory": [
                        {
                            "id": "76a6ead4-9f4d-4d6e-9c30-70938f088ea3",
                            "Name": "string",
                            "Description": "string",
                            "Product": [
                                {
                                    "Id": "abf95277-ccbc-4f9d-aeda-b6cc9c99953b",
                                    "Name": "string",
                                    "CurrentQuantity": 0,
                                    "Tag": "string",
                                    "Unit": "string",
                                    "Price": 0,
                                    "hasMethodOfPreparation": true,
                                    "MethodOfPreparation": [
                                        {
                                            "id": "a78cb9ea-276f-494b-840a-6eab5e7d8f4b",
                                            "Description": "string",
                                            "Price": 0
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "Addons": [
                                        {
                                            "id": "bdf97be3-5dd1-49e9-bdec-7ac0d3288adb",
                                            "Description": "one",
                                            "Price": 0
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "id": "8f03d2e2-be1f-446d-b943-be9b8fe8ec4c",
                                            "Description": "new add",
                                            "Price": 0
```

I query the data like blow
query:

```
SELECT product FROM catalog 
join industry in catalog.Industy 
join category in industry.Category 
join product in category.Subcategory.Product 
where catalog.id ='" + itemId + "'
```

actual result:For a specific vendor ,industry ,category,sub category i need to get and create product.
note: here more than one indutry,category,sub category .

```
                       {
                                 "Id": "abf95277-ccbc-4f9d-aeda-b6cc9c99953b",
                                    "Name": "string",
                                    "CurrentQuantity": 0,
                                    "Tag": "string",
                                    "Unit": "string",
                                    "Price": 0,
                                    "hasMethodOfPreparation": true,
                                    "MethodOfPreparation": [
                                        {
                                            "id": "a78cb9ea-276f-494b-840a-6eab5e7d8f4b",
                                            "Description": "string",
                                            "Price": 0
                                        }
```

but i need to check the industry id ,category id and sub category id. 
How to do that,
Please give me suggestion. thanks in advance .

Comment: i am using cosmosdb

Comment: What do you mean you need to check the industry id ,category id and sub category id? You mean you wan to query them? or filter them? You sample data is incomplete,please complete it and give more details about your needs.

Comment: i need to get the product for a specific vendor,industry,category and sub category .there are more than one vendor,industry,category or sub category

Comment: So what's the filter condition then?or would you please list your desire result format?I tried to generate the sql....

Comment: filter condition should check industry ,category ,sub category id

Comment: result should retive   the product and add the product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use sql:

```
SELECT product FROM c 
join industry in c.Industy 
join category in industry.Category 
join Subcategory in category.Subcategory
join product in Subcategory.Product 
where industry.Id ='<your item id>' 
and category.Id = '<your item id>' 
and Subcategory.Id = '<your item id>'
```

Output:

[image]